# How to create autocomplete textbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I want to create a textbox that works like ajax auto complete control in wpf and search the data from database not web services

Please guide me

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you need WPF control, if not - please correct me and provide more details to the question ("How to create autocomplete textbox in WPF?"). Basically you can use out of the box [WPFToolkit AutocompleteBox](http://wpf.codeplex.com/), usage is pretty straightforward:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                         Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" 
                         FilterMode="None" />
```

And this is up to you how to implement `Items` property in the bound data source, it could be a linq-to-sql query or static list, whatever.